# Skip to next user input in a for loop

Tags: java, loops

If I wanted to change some data, but keep some of the original names, how could I skip to the next user input when I press Enter?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("Press Enter to skip to next input");
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
//If user presses Enter/newline, go to the next part where it asks for Name2

    Name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You've entered: " + Name);
    myVector.elementAt(i).setName(Name);

    System.out.println("Press Enter to skip to next input");
    System.out.print("Enter Name2: ");

    Name2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You've entered: " + Name2);
    myVector.elementAt(i).setName(Name2);

//...etc
}
```

Comment: like if(Name == "\n") continue?

Comment: @user1615805 It would actually have to be `if (Name.equals("\n"))`, since "\n" is a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Name = keyboard.nextLine();
if (!Name.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("You've entered: " + Name);
  myVector.elementAt(i).setName(Name);
}
```

That is, if `Name` is empty, skip it to `Name2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the continue keyword ([from oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)).

Answer (score 1):

```
loop: for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(user presses enter) {
        System.out.println("Press Enter to skip to next input");
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        //If user presses Enter/newline, go to the next part where it asks for Name2

        continue loop;
    }    
    else {
        Name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You've entered: " + Name);
        myVector.elementAt(i).setName(Name);

        System.out.println("Press Enter to skip to next input");
        System.out.print("Enter Name2: ");

        Name2 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You've entered: " + Name2);
        myVector.elementAt(i).setName(Name2);

        //...etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a jump label it not necessary in this example.

Comment: @user1168261 yes, but ijust added for better understanding